# Data from row into no php-site for edit

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have a problem with my php-code. On the first site is a list with all the data. The table of the data is correctly displayed. In the last column of the table is a link placed to the next page which should hand over the id of the row.

Here's the link:

```
print '<a href="editsr.php?id='.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-default btn1">Ändern</a>';
```

But I can't now get the data into the input fields for edit. The form show up correct, but i have in every input field this error:

> **Warning**:  Illegal string offset 'vorname' in **/home_pr5/d/e/deniseli.ch/htdocs/www.deniseli.ch/T .... tor/editsr.php** on line **130**
> S

Here's the editsr.php:

```html
<?php
session_start();
require_once("inc/config.inc.php");
require_once("inc/functions.inc.php");

$id = $_GET['id'];
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id");
$result = $statement->execute(array('id' => ['id']));
$user = $statement->fetch();


include("templates/header.inc.php");

if(isset($_GET['save'])) {
 $save = $_GET['save'];
 
 if($save == 'personal_data') {
  $vorname = trim($_POST['vorname']);
  $nachname = trim($_POST['nachname']);
  $adresse = trim($_POST['adresse']);
  $plz = trim($_POST['plz']);
  $ort = trim($_POST['ort']);
  $geburtstag = trim($_POST['geburtstag']);
  $handy = trim($_POST['handy']);
  $liga = trim($_POST['liga']);
  $verein = trim($_POST['verein']);
  $bank = trim($_POST['bank']);
  $iban = trim($_POST['iban']);
  
  if($vorname == "" || $nachname == "" || $adresse == "" || $plz == "" || $ort == "" || $handy == "" || $liga == "" || $verein == "") {
   $error_msg = "Bitte alle Angaben ausfüllen.";
  } else {
   $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET vorname = :vorname, nachname = :nachname, adresse = :adresse, plz = :plz, ort = :ort, geburtstag = :geburtstag, handy = :handy, liga = :liga, verein = :verein, bank = :bank, iban = :iban, id = :id, updated_at=NOW() WHERE id = $id");
   $result = $statement->execute(array('vorname' => $vorname, 'nachname'=> $nachname,'adresse' => $adresse, 'plz' => $plz, 'ort' => $ort, 'geburtstag' => $geburtstag, 'handy' => $handy, 'liga' => $liga, 'verein' => $verein,'bank' => $bank, 'iban' => $iban, 'id' => $user['id'] ));
   
   $success_msg = "Daten erfolgreich gespeichert.";
  }
 } else if($save == 'email') {
  $passwort = $_POST['passwort'];
  $email = trim($_POST['email']);
  $email2 = trim($_POST['email2']);
  
  if($email != $email2) {
   $error_msg = "Die eingegebenen E-Mail-Adressen stimmten nicht überein.";
  } else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   $error_msg = "Bitte eine gültige E-Mail-Adresse eingeben.";
  } else if(!password_verify($passwort, $user['passwort'])) {
   $error_msg = "Bitte korrektes Passwort eingeben.";
  } else {
   $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET email = :email WHERE id = $id");
   $result = $statement->execute(array('email' => $email));
    
   $success_msg = "E-Mail-Adresse erfolgreich gespeichert.";
  }
  
 } else if($save == 'passwort') {
  $passwortAlt = $_POST['passwortAlt'];
  $passwortNeu = trim($_POST['passwortNeu']);
  $passwortNeu2 = trim($_POST['passwortNeu2']);
  
  if($passwortNeu != $passwortNeu2) {
   $error_msg = "Die eingegebenen Passwörter stimmten nicht überein.";
  } else if($passwortNeu == "") {
   $error_msg = "Das Passwort darf nicht leer sein.";
  } else if(!password_verify($passwortAlt, $user['passwort'])) {
   $error_msg = "Bitte korrektes Passwort eingeben.";
  } else {
   $passwort_hash = password_hash($passwortNeu, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    
   $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET passwort = :passwort WHERE id = $id");
   $result = $statement->execute(array('passwort' => $passwort_hash));
    
   $success_msg = "Passwort erfolgreich gespeichert.";
   
  }
 }
}


?>

<div class="container main-container">

<h1>Schiedsrichter Profil bearbeiten</h1>

<?php 
if(isset($success_msg) && !empty($success_msg)):
?>
 <div class="alert alert-success">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    <?php echo $success_msg; ?>
 </div>
<?php 
endif;
?>

<?php 
if(isset($error_msg) && !empty($error_msg)):
?>
 <div class="alert alert-danger">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    <?php echo $error_msg; ?>
 </div>
<?php 
endif;
?>

<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Übersicht</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#data" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Persönliche Daten</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#email" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">E-Mail</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#passwort" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Passwort</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Übersicht-->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
     <br>
     <form action="?save=personal_data&id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for=inputVorname class="col-sm-2 control-label">Vorname</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputVorname" name="vorname" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['vorname']); ?>" readonly>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputNachname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nachname</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputNachname" name="nachname" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['nachname']); ?>" readonly>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputAdresse" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Adresse</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputAdresse" name="adresse" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['adresse']); ?>" readonly>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputPLZ" class="col-sm-2 control-label">PLZ</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputPLZ" name="plz" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['plz']); ?>" readonly>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputOrt" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ort</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputOrt" name="ort" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['ort']); ?>" readonly>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputGeburtstag" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Geburtsdatum</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputGeburtstag" name="geburtstag" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['geburtstag']); ?>" readonly>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">E-Mail</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="email" type="email" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['email']); ?>" readonly>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputHandy" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Handy</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputHandy" name="handy" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['handy']); ?>" readonly>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputLiga" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Liga</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputLiga" name="liga" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['liga']); ?>" readonly>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputVerein" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Verein</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputVerein" name="verein" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['verein']); ?>" readonly>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputBank" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Bankname</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputBank" name="bank" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['bank']); ?>" readonly>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputIban" class="col-sm-2 control-label">IBAN</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputIban" name="iban" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['iban']); ?>" readonly>
       </div>
      </div>
      
     </form>
    </div>

  <!-- Persönliche Daten-->
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="data">
     <br>
     <form action="?save=personal_data&id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputVorname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Vorname</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputVorname" name="vorname" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['vorname']); ?>" required>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputNachname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nachname</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputNachname" name="nachname" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['nachname']); ?>" required>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputAdresse" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Adresse</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputAdresse" name="adresse" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['adresse']); ?>" required>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputPLZ" class="col-sm-2 control-label">PLZ</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputPLZ" name="plz" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['plz']); ?>" required>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputOrt" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ort</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputOrt" name="ort" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['ort']); ?>" required>
       </div>
      </div>
            
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputGeburtstag" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Geburtsdatum</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputGeburtstag" name="geburtstag" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['geburtstag']); ?>" placeholder="01.01.2000">
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputHandy" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Handy</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputHandy" name="handy" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['handy']); ?>" required>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputLiga" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Liga</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputLiga" name="liga" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['liga']); ?>" required>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputVerein" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Verein</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputVerein" name="verein" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['verein']); ?>" required>
       </div>
      </div>
            
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputBank" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Bankname</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputBank" name="bank" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['bank']); ?>" placeholder="Postfinance">
       </div>
      </div>
      
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputIban" class="col-sm-2 control-label">IBAN</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputIban" name="iban" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['iban']); ?>" placeholder="CHxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx x">
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Speichern</button>
         <a class="btn btn-danger" href='internal.php'>Abbrechen</a>
       </div>
   </div>
     </form>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Änderung der E-Mail-Adresse -->
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="email">
     <br>
     <p>Zum Änderen deiner E-Mail-Adresse gib bitte dein aktuelles Passwort sowie die neue E-Mail-Adresse ein.</p>
     <form action="?save=email&id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputPasswort" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Passwort</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputPasswort" name="passwort" type="password" required>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">E-Mail</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="email" type="email" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['email']); ?>" required>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputEmail2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">E-Mail (wiederholen)</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail2" name="email2" type="email"  required>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Speichern</button>
         <a class="btn btn-danger" href='spielliste.php'>Abbrechen</a>
       </div>
   </div>
     </form>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Änderung des Passworts -->
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="passwort">
     <br>
     <p>Zum Änderen deines Passworts gib bitte dein aktuelles Passwort sowie das neue Passwort ein.</p>
     <form action="?save=passwort&id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputPasswort" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Altes Passwort</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputPasswort" name="passwortAlt" type="password" required>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputPasswortNeu" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Neues Passwort</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputPasswortNeu" name="passwortNeu" type="password" required>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputPasswortNeu2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Neues Passwort (wiederholen)</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputPasswortNeu2" name="passwortNeu2" type="password"  required>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Speichern</button>
         <a class="btn btn-danger" href='spielliste.php'>Abbrechen</a>
       </div>
   </div>
     </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<?php 
include("templates/footer.inc.php")
?>
```

**UPDATE:** new code editsr.php. Works fine with the tabs, only the changes displayed after refresh the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your code carefully

on the top you are using the $user variable like below

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id");
$result = $statement->execute(array('id' => ['id']));
$user = $statement->fetch(); // here
```

and again on the bottom of php code you are using $user variable like below

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id"; // here

?>
```

on the input you are trying to get like `htmlentities($user['vorname']);`

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for=inputVorname class="col-sm-2 control-label">Vorname</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input class="form-control" id="inputVorname" name="vorname" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['vorname']); ?>" readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
```

that's the problem of error in every input :)

Comment: hmm. but i have no clue what i have to insert else into the input.

Comment: Try this format for all inputs, check the variable is isset using like value="<?php if(isset($user['vorname'])) {  echo htmlentities($user['vorname']); } else { echo ""; } ?>"  or simply user @$user['vorname'] to hide error

Comment: it doesn't work. now, every input is empty, but i haven't the data which i'd like to edit displayed. it seems like the data haven't come thru. the 'id' is correct, but every orther cell not.

Comment: Have you removed the code ?

$id = $_GET['id'];
$user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id"; // here

if not remove and run the code

Comment: yes i have removed the code : $id = $_GET['id']; $user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id" on the bottom. no errors but still no data..

Comment: where you are passing the id $id = $_GET['id'];  in your form action no parameters id <form action="?save=personal_data" method="post" class="form-horizontal"> pass the id like  <form action="?save=personal_data&id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal"> and try now

Comment: ok. all the data are now in the input fields. but i've i press de submit button for save, nothing happens.

Comment: check your code there is no submit button inside the first form

Comment: yes, true. first one is only as overview. but the second tab of the form is for editing.

      <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Speichern</button>
         <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href='settings.php'">Cancel</button>
       </div>
   </div>

Comment: when you click submit button, the form corrosponding to the submit is only posted, not all the form, so make the form a single, remove the multiple form and make one form with one submit button

Comment: so i tried that, but same problem. If i press submit, it clears all the input fields but nothing happens. Now updates were made.

Comment: now it works perfectly fine, except that new content after submitting is not updated. but after a page refresh, is right.
maybe you've got an idea for that.

Comment: Update your code in the question with the work you have done. i will check

Comment: may i know the plugin you are using for tabpanel?

Comment: not sure what you mean but im working with Bootstrap: tab.js v3.3.6

Comment: After the update done in database, re select the data that is repeat the below code at above the
 ?>

<div class="container main-container">
 
// Code to repeat
$id = $_GET['id'];
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id");
$result = $statement->execute(array('id' => ['id']));
$user = $statement->fetch();

Comment: get the updated data from database by repeating the fetch

$id = $_GET['id']; $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id"); $result = $statement->execute(array('id' => ['id'])); $user = $statement->fetch();

at bottom of php

Answer (score 0):

New Code with only one form:

```html
<?php
session_start();
require_once("inc/config.inc.php");
require_once("inc/functions.inc.php");

$id = $_GET['id'];
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id");
$result = $statement->execute(array('id' => ['id']));
$user = $statement->fetch();


include("templates/header.inc.php");

if(isset($_GET['save'])) {
 $save = $_GET['save'];
 
 if($save == 'personal_data') {
  $vorname = trim($_POST['vorname']);
  $nachname = trim($_POST['nachname']);
  $adresse = trim($_POST['adresse']);
  $plz = trim($_POST['plz']);
  $ort = trim($_POST['ort']);
  $geburtstag = trim($_POST['geburtstag']);
  $handy = trim($_POST['handy']);
  $email = trim($_POST['email']);
  $liga = trim($_POST['liga']);
  $verein = trim($_POST['verein']);
  $bank = trim($_POST['bank']);
  $iban = trim($_POST['iban']);
  $passwortNeu = trim($_POST['passwortNeu']);
  
  if($vorname == "" || $nachname == "" || $adresse == "" || $plz == "" || $ort == "" || $handy == "" || $liga == "" || $verein == "" || $email == "" || $passwortNeu == "" ){
   $error_msg = "Bitte alle Angaben ausfüllen.";
  } else {
   $passwort_hash = password_hash($passwortNeu, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
   $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET vorname = :vorname, nachname = :nachname, adresse = :adresse, plz = :plz, ort = :ort, geburtstag = :geburtstag, handy = :handy, liga = :liga, verein = :verein, bank = :bank, iban = :iban, passwort = :passwort, email = :email, updated_at=NOW() WHERE id = $id");
   $result = $statement->execute(array('vorname' => $vorname, 'nachname'=> $nachname,'adresse' => $adresse, 'plz' => $plz, 'ort' => $ort, 'geburtstag' => $geburtstag, 'handy' => $handy, 'liga' => $liga, 'verein' => $verein,'bank' => $bank, 'iban' => $iban, 'passwort' => $passwort_hash, 'email' => $email));
   
   $success_msg = "Daten erfolgreich gespeichert.";
   
  }
 } 
}

?>

<div class="container main-container">

<h1>Schiedsrichter Profil bearbeiten</h1>

<?php 
if(isset($success_msg) && !empty($success_msg)):
?>
 <div class="alert alert-success">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    <?php echo $success_msg; ?>
 </div>
<?php 
endif;
?>

<?php 
if(isset($error_msg) && !empty($error_msg)):
?>
 <div class="alert alert-danger">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    <?php echo $error_msg; ?>
 </div>
<?php 
endif;
?>

<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#data" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Persönliche Daten</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Persönliche Daten-->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="data">
     <br>
     <form action="?save=personal_data" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputVorname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Vorname</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputVorname" name="vorname" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['vorname']); ?>" required>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputNachname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nachname</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputNachname" name="nachname" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['nachname']); ?>" required>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputAdresse" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Adresse</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputAdresse" name="adresse" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['adresse']); ?>" required>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputPLZ" class="col-sm-2 control-label">PLZ</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputPLZ" name="plz" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['plz']); ?>" required>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputOrt" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ort</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputOrt" name="ort" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['ort']); ?>" required>
       </div>
      </div>
            
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputGeburtstag" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Geburtsdatum</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputGeburtstag" name="geburtstag" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['geburtstag']); ?>" placeholder="01.01.2000">
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputHandy" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Handy</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputHandy" name="handy" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['handy']); ?>" required>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">E-Mail</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="email" type="email" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['email']); ?>" required>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputLiga" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Liga</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputLiga" name="liga" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['liga']); ?>" required>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputVerein" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Verein</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputVerein" name="verein" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['verein']); ?>" required>
       </div>
      </div>
            
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputBank" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Bankname</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputBank" name="bank" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['bank']); ?>" placeholder="Postfinance">
       </div>
      </div>
      
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputIban" class="col-sm-2 control-label">IBAN</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputIban" name="iban" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['iban']); ?>" placeholder="CHxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx x">
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="inputPasswortNeu" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Neues Passwort</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputPasswortNeu" name="passwortNeu" type="password" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['passwort']); ?>" required>
       </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Speichern</button>
         <a class="btn btn-danger" href='internal.php'>Abbrechen</a>
       </div>
   </div>
     </form>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<?php 
include("templates/footer.inc.php")
?>
```